# 2005 Chevy hubs

Tags: comprehension

Example:

> The Web is changing how we do everything and creating new standards for commerce, education, and communication. Want to know how much something is worth? Go to eBay. It's the ultimate free market, where the value of anything is quickly determined by a few bids **that tell you**—in real terms, not some economic gobbledygook—**the most that anyone in the world would pay for a set of 2005 Chevy hubs**.

I don't think I can comprehend that part well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *set of 2005 Chevy hubs* is a set (presumably 4) of wheel hubs (probably with the bearings) for a 2005 Chevrolet:

[image: Hub and bearing]

This is mentioned as representative of goods which have a very limited and scattered market. If you want to know how much you, as a private individual, should ask or pay for such goods, you can find out by looking at the bids on eBay, which will tell you the highest price people are willing to pay.